# Convert concrete implementation type to generic interface type

Tags: c#

I have interfaces and implementations like this:

```
public interface IRequest
{
   string Name{set;get;}
}

public class UppercaseRequest: IRequest
{
    public string Name{get; set}
}

public interface IHandler<T> where T: IRequest
{
   void Handle(T request);
}

public class UpperCaseHandler : IHandler<UpperCaseRequest>
{
     //implementation interface here
}
```

And a factory like this:

```
public class HandlerFactory
{
    public IHandler<T> CreateHandler(T request) where T: IRequest
    {
       switch(request.Name)
       {
         case "UpperCase": return new UpperCaseHandler() as IHandler<T>;
                           //this line compile but always return null;
       }
    }
}
```

That handler method in `HandlerFactory` always returns null. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this behavior? Can you also give me some advice on how I can improve the code structure?

Comment: How do you call the handler method?

Comment: @GvS i call it by like this: 
foreach( var request in request)
{
 var handler = factory.CreateHandler(request);
 handler.Handle(request);
}

Comment: Why `UpperCaseHandler` class declared as generic? Also, please spedn some time and make your code compile (at least interfaces with their implementations)

Comment: Have you tried debugging and putting a breakpoint inside rhe Handle method?

Comment: @RodTalingting yes, i put a breakpoint inside the caller, that method in HandlerFactory returned null

Comment: @OlivierRogier i'm sorry, i will edit the code

Comment: I think you're doing it wrong. Im notnsure why you want to return an instance of uppeecasehandler class  You use handler to handle stuff inside the Handle method. Depending on the data/object you pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a modified and corrected code that works like a charm. We have the reference to an instance. But I don't know if it was you want...

The factory class should be static, isn't it ?

[image]

```
static void Test()
{
  var a = new HandlerFactory().CreateHandler(new UpperCaseRequest() { Name = "UpperCase" });
}
```

```
public class HandlerFactory
{
  public IHandler<T> CreateHandler<T>(T request) where T : IRequest
  {
    switch ( request.Name )
    {
      case "UpperCase": return new UpperCaseHandler() as IHandler<T>;
    }
    return default(IHandler<T>);
  }
}

public interface IRequest
{
  string Name { set; get; }
}

public class UpperCaseRequest : IRequest
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IHandler<T> where T : IRequest
{
  void Handle(T request);
}

public class UpperCaseHandler : IHandler<UpperCaseRequest>
{
  public void Handle(UpperCaseRequest request)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```